# iPhone UILabel properties

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I'm trying to set a shadow on my UILabel.

I'd like the shadow to be at a -90 degree angle, 1 px distance, 55% opacity and 0px size.

How above can this implemented ?

Comment: I think reading the documentation would be a good start

Comment: what do you mean 0px size? You want the font size to be 0px large?

Comment: I guess 0px size corresponds to Photoshop's blur.

Comment: 0px size sounds like font size to me, but that doesn't make much sense (kinda like the rest of the question). If its blue size, default bluring is none, so it would be 0px by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure px distance is determined by font, if it isn't i cant find a way to get to it.

```
UITextLabel *label = [[[UITextLabel alloc] init] autorelease];

//Shadow straight down
[label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0,1)];

//55% opacity
[label setShadowColor:[[label shadowColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.55]];
```

Comment: Ummm, how is that not what he wants?

Comment: I guess he wants the shadow to have 55% opacity. Also, he didn't mention the font size at all. ;)

Comment: He probably means blur with 'size'

Comment: you are correct, I didn't realize he wanted all those properties on the shadow, and not the text label. I applied the properties to the label :P, corrected code

Comment: Right. My answer should do what he wants :P

Comment: Mine uses the current shadow color of the label instead of hard coding it black (all though he probably wants a black shadow, so probably wouldn't matter), ;)

Comment: @ColdLogic let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1631/discussion-between-jenox-and-coldlogic)

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextLabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
label.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.55];
```

You would have to replace the blackColor with whatever you want.
I guess that you cannot blur the shadow, but you seem not to want that anyway.